# How to make compact grid with resizable JButtons?

Tags: java, swing, layout

I am trying to reuse Swing SpringLayout compact grid functionality to make a compact grid of resizable JButtons using:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html

It works fine but SpringLayout can not resise JButtons so it is useless for me.
Is there some other way to create a compact grid with resizable Jbuttons on it?

Comment: Use GridLayout, use GridBagLayout, write your own LayoutManager.

Comment: I tried to use GridLayout and GridBagLayout. Problems with them that column width is the same for all columns.

Comment: How can I write my own LayoutManager?

Comment: Why do you (choose one) a) use a LayoutManager that is not meant for manual usage b) reinvent the wheel in a custom implementation? Have a look at powerful third-party managers, like FormLayout, MigLayout, DesignGridLayout

Answer (score 2):

```
A: Use GridLayout, use GridBagLayout, write your own LayoutManager.
Q: How can I write my own LayoutManager?
```

please no, for Swing Guru like as @StanislavL isn't somehow complicated to wrote own `LayoutManager`, for rest of us is better to use [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) or `GridBagLayout`,

Answer (score 1):

You can use GridBagLayout for this. Here is a sample that shows two buttons - one maintains its width and the other one changes its width when the frame is resized.

Note the GridBagConstraints that tell the component how it should behave in the layout. The weight controls the resize behaviour. Further information can be found in the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

```
package test;

import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class LayoutResizeButtonTest extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LayoutResizeButtonTest app = new LayoutResizeButtonTest();

        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        app.setVisible(true);

    }

    LayoutResizeButtonTest() {

        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 1.0;

        this.add(new Button("Resizable"), c);

        c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.weightx = 0.0;

        this.add(new Button("Not Resizable"));

        this.pack();

    }

}
```

Comment: But how I can create compact grid using GridBagLayout?

Comment: @user1253040 what do you mean by "compact grid"?

Comment: In GridBagLayout each component in column have the same width- maximum width of all columns. Compact grid means that column width is maximum component width in column.